# Where can I find a PHP Tag File for SlickEdit?

Tags: php, text-editor, slickedit

I'm trying out SlickEdit and it says it can use a "tag file" for PHP.  Does anyone know where I can find this tag file?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question.  This is not about updating a tag file.  This is about getting the first one with a new install!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It supports the ability to create a tag file on PHP source code.  You still need to point it in the direction of the PHP source code.

To create these tag files, go Tools | Tag Files... | Add Tag File...

Select PHP and then add the directories containing your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Tag files are basically an index of names in your code project that are spread across files. This can be used for jumping between files and auto-completion. Some relevant information about the concept is here on Wikipedia: [Ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags).

As for creating it in SlickEdit, check the section "Building and Managing Tag Files" in the help. You should be able to use the Tools -> Tag Files dialog to add files that you want to index.

Answer (score 1):

According to "[SlickEdit 2008 - Languages Supported](http://www.slickedit.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=160&Itemid=57)," SlickEdit already supports PHP, out of the box.  When you install it, no tag file is included?  It looks like it should already exist.